# phpmyadmin - mbstring extension is missing in php 7.4

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, php-7.4

php version :7.4.8
OS: ubuntu

> when I try to localhost/phpmyadmin am getting this error

The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration.

and I already install mbstring

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-mbstring is already the newest version (2:7.4+76+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+9).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    php-mbstring is already the newest version (2:7.4+76+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+9).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I try this method as well

1. I find php.ini
2. I search extension=php_mbstring.dll

but ;extension=php_mbstring.dll is missing in php.ini file

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: your PHP was installed with the apt-get command ? Check if you doesn't have a second version of PHP in the package list, like php7.4

Comment: only one its 7.4

Comment: /etc/php in here I have only one that is 7.4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried giving the version?

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring
```

Comment: This results in `E: Unable to locate package php7.4-mbstring`

Comment: @Jeff Probably the packages are missing. Do:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx -y`
`sudo apt update`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to install the composer dependency **symfony/polyfill**
It covers the use of **mbstring** functions.

if you haven't already installed, head over to http://getcomposer.org
then

```
composer require symfony/polyfill
```

Composer is best-practice and widely used from many open source projects around the world so don't worry.